# Angular Router not routing correctly with Absolute Path in subdirectory

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to get Angular router to navigate to an absolute path when the site is hosted in a subdirectory.

Currently the site is hosted at:
www.example.com/ngSite/

As an example I have this code in a click event

```
onClick(primaryLink){
    let link: string = primaryLink.getAttribute('href');
    //I expect link to look like this: /ngSite/path/to/thing
    this.router.navigateByUrl([link]);
}
```

This should navigate to:

> www.example.com/ngSite/path/to/thing

But instead navigates to (notice the duplicate subdirectory):

> www.example.com/*ngSite*/ngSite/path/to/thing

In the documentation on angular.io it says

> Always specify the complete absolute path when calling router's navigateByUrl method.

Which is what I think I am doing. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the base tag in your index.html? Mabye try with `"." + link`

Comment: Yes, add `<base href="/ngSite/" />` to the `<head>` section of your page, so that Angular knows it's running in a sub directory. After doing so, you won't need to include "ngSite" in any of the URLs in your app.

Comment: SunilD. I have the base href set to <base href="/ngSite/" />

@Wernerson I tried "." + Link but that didn't change how it works.

Comment: I tried link with ".."+link and that works but it feels wrong.

Comment: Wait nevermind. It doesn't actually route it

Comment: I have similar issue:  navigateByUrl("importer/step2") from the component gotten to by navigateByUrl("importer/step1") doesn't take me to importer/step2, but instead importer/step1/step2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by invoking the click event on the passed in element.

So my simple example would change to look something like this:

```
onClick(primaryLink){
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(primaryLink, 'click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a redirect in your routes, like this:

`RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'whatever' },
    { path: 'whatever', component: WhateverController },`

Try replacing the redirectTo with the actual component.

`RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: '', component: WhateverController },
    { path: 'whatever', component: WhateverController },`

This helped my related issue with a wrong URL being produced.

Comment: I don't have a redirect at the problem areas of my app. I did have one at the root level and changing that did not fix the issue.